# Dynamic custom fields: JSON, Pivot, morphToMany?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm currently working on a "custom fields" feature for my Laravel-app.

### What it's supposed to do

Each `CustomField` should be editable by the user. The `CustomField` can have a `type` (`string`, `int`, ...) and a `value`.

Now the created `CustomField`s can be added to another model (Maybe: `User`).

### Expected result

The values of the custom fields should be callable using something like `$user->fields->company->value`

It should be easy to iterate through the fields like this: `$user->fields()->each(...)`

### My problem

I'm not sure which way to go: Of course I could just create a model called `CustomField` and a table with

- `id`
- `type`

and save them to the `User` as JSON (`$user->fields` would be type `JSON`). But I am not sure, whether this is the best way to go, because I also would like to make the fields searchable later. So maybe *pivot* is the way to go? Or even *morphToMany*?

Which way is the most "Laravel-style" way to go?

Thank you for your thoughts (and maybe 1-2 examples ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

The application structure is not unique and it may be implemented differently developer to developer.
However, The best practice, in this case, could be a separated model for `CustomField`.

1. In order to effectively use the custom fields value as searchable, the Laravel Scout is a very powerful choice, which provides a simple, driver-based solution for adding full-text search to your Eloquent models.
2. As far as I understand your problem, every user has many `CustomFields`. So better to have in different table and model.